# upload zip and rar file using node.js and multer to cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer, cloudinary

i'm traying to upload rar and zip file using multer to cloudinary , i upload pdf it works fine, but i want to allow only zip and rar.

here is my code:

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, curDate + file.originalname);
  }
});

var DocFilter = function (req, file, cb) {
    // accept image files only
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(pdf||doc|docx)$/i)) {
        return cb(new Error('Only document files are allowed!'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
};
var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: DocFilter})
```

i tryed switching to this `file.originalname.match(/\.(/|zip|rar)$/i` 
but it did not work

and here is the route:

```
router.post("/requestsList" , middleware.isLoggedIn ,  upload.single("attach") , function(req , res){
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result) {
    var Name = req.body.name ;
    var Gender = req.body.gender ;
    var Email = req.body.email ;
    var PNumber = req.body.phone ;
    var attach = result.secure_url;

var newRequest = {Name: Name , Gender: Gender , Email: Email , PhonenNumber: PNumber , Attachment: attach} ;
Request.create(newRequest , function(err , newlyCreated){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
       req.flash("error" , err.message);
       res.redirect("back");
   } else{
       console.log(newlyCreated);
       req.flash("success" , "Request Successfully Sent");
       res.redirect("/home") ;
   }
});
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

*This is more of a comment but I don't have the reputation for it.*

I think you have a typo in your RegExp.
There's an extra slash.

That should fix your problem.

```
file.originalname.match(/\.(/|zip|rar)$/i
                            ^
                            |
```

Comment: when i removed it the error is gone, but now when i upload it, it says undefined

Comment: Can you clarify more, what says undefined, what is "it" ?

Comment: when i try to upload the attached file with extension zip or rar, and try to console.log it, like this: var attach = result.secure_url; console.log("attach==> " + attach); it print attach==> undefined

Comment: I'm not sure about that but the cause could be that Cloudinary might not support rar/zip files. As far as I can tell from their [website](https://cloudinary.com/about), they only support Image files

Comment: Cloudinary definitely supports uploading of zip files if you set the `resource_type` parameter to `raw`, though depending on your plan the file size limit might be lower than the zip file you're trying to upload: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_non_image_files_as_raw_files